# Vim variables, expandtab and noexpandtab, one exists and the other does not?

Tags: variables, types, vim

I am kind of confused about how Vimscript variables work, for example, with regards to the variables expandtab and noexpandtab, which would seem to be opposites of one another. If I ask vim,

```
:set expandtab?
```

it answers `noexpandtab`. If I ask it,

```
:echo &expandtab
```

it answers `0`. If I ask it

```
:set noexpandtab?
```

it answers `noexpandtab` again. But if I ask it

```
:echo &noexpandtab
```

It answers:

```
E113: Unknown option: noexpandtab
E15: Invalid expression: &noexpandtab
```

So, I guess I don't understand. If `noexpandtab` is a variable then why can't I echo its value? And if it is not a variable then what is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You are dealing with options, here, not variables.
- `noexpandtab` is not an option, it's `no` followed by an actual option name. This notation allows you to use the `:set` command to switch a boolean option off.
- The `&option` notation is used to work with the value of `option` as an expression. It can only be used with actual option names (short or long) so it won't work with `noexpandtab` which is not a valid option name.

  ```
  " switch expandtab on
  :set expandtab        :let &expandtab = 1

  " switch expandtab off
  :set noexpandtab      :let &expandtab = 0

  " see what's the value of expandtab
  :set expandtab?       :echo &expandtab
  ```

Answer (score 2):

From the help file (options.txt):

> :se[t] no{option} Toggle option: Reset, switch it off.

The option is `expandtab`. There is no option or variable with the name `noexpandtab`.

Answer (score 1):

If you say

```
set expandtab
set expandtab?
echo &expandtab
```

you get `expandtab` and `1` respectively. I'm not entirely sure on the answer, but by looking at this and from your question, `expandtab` is the variable name, thus `&expandtab` is the pointer to this variable. When `expandtab==1` it is on, and off when `expandtab==0`. So I would guess that when you call

```
set expandtab?
```

or

```
set noexpandtab?
```

you are  actually calling the same thing. You are asking vim whether `expandtab` is on or off. Instead of returning a `0` or `1`, which could mean different things depending on whether you asked `expandtab?` or `noexpandtab?`, it tells you exactly what the setting is.

So I'm saying that `noexpandtab` isn't actually a variable, it's just an alias for `expandtab` when it's set to `0`.

But again, this is just an educated guess.

**EDIT**: Update from @Amadan's comment
`expandtab` is the option, and `&expandtab` is the variable or value of the option. In this case, `expandtab` is a boolean option (you can either have it on (1) or off (0)). `noexpandtab` is just the syntax for `expandtab` being set to `off`.

Comment: `&` is not an address operator as it is in C. `&opt` is the vimscript syntax for the value of the option `opt` (options are distinct from variables).

Comment: What @KeithThompson said. Note that `set` works with options, `let` works with variables (and `&opt` lets you treat an option as a variable). `set noXXX` is the syntax for setting boolean option `XXX` to false, so there is in fact no `noexpandtab` option, nor `&noexpandtab` variable. There is also `set invXXX` to toggle options, and it would make no kind of sense to have a variable `&invexpandtab` - what would its value be? :)